# How to map an array inside JSON object using typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm trying to get an array from a JSON object and then, map it in order to get the data.
Here is the data returned from an API:

```
{
  project: [
    {
      _createdAt: '2022-12-15T16:45:57Z',
      _id: 'cb39338d-4e6d-4c28-9a79-499afca392e6',
      _rev: '974wCYB6EQ3xW9LGNZhQvU',
      _type: 'project',
      _updatedAt: '2022-12-27T04:55:54Z',
      image: [Object],
      linkToBuild: 'https://github.com/Arotiana137-51/charitty_to_portfolio_jsp',
      summary: "This is a project I've done for learning purpose at the University. I've learned the basics of web programing  with  Java Server Pages ,Servelet ,....",      technologies: [Array],
      title: 'Charity '
    }
  ]
}
```

And I wish to map this array in order to get elements from it inside this JSX element :

```
import React from "react";
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';
import { Project } from "../typing";
import { urlFor } from "../sanity";
type Props = {
  projects:Project[];
};

function Projects({projects}: Props) {
   console.log(projects);
  return (
    <motion.div 
    initial={{opacity:0}}
    whileInView={{opacity:1}}
    transition={{duration:1.5}}
    className="h-screen relative flex overflow-hidden flex-col text-left md:flex-row max-w-full justify-evenly mx-auto items-center z-0">
      <h3 className="absolute top-24 uppercase tracking-widest text-teal-400 text-2xl ">
        Projects
      </h3>

      <div className="relative w-full flex overflow-x-scroll overflow-y-hidden snap-x snap-mandatory z-20">
       {/*----------- HERE I TRY TO ACCESS THE ARRAY AND MAP IT DIRECTLY, LIKE IN JS-----------------------------------*/} 
           { projects.project.map((project,i) => ( 
           <div className="w-screen flex-shrink-0 snap-center  flex flex-col space-y-5 items-center justify-center p-20 md:p-44 h-screen">
                <motion.img
                initial ={{
                  y: -300,
                  opacity:0
                }}
                transition={{duration: 1.2}}
                whileInView = {{opacity:1 , y:0 }}
                viewport={{ once: true}}
                
                src={urlFor(project.image).url()}
                alt="#"/>
            

            <div className=" space-y-10 px-0 md:px-10 max-w-6xl ">
                <h4 className="text-4xl font-semibold text-center">
                Case study {i+1} of{projects.length}: <span className="underline decoration-teal-700"> {project?.title}</span>
                </h4>
                <div className="flex items-center space-x-2 justify-center">
                  {
                    project?.technologies.map((technology)=>(
                      <img 
                      className="h-10 w-10"
                      key={technology._id}
                      src={urlFor(technology?.image).url()}
                      alt=""
                      />
                    ))
                  }
                </div>

                <p>{project?.summary}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
               ))}
      </div>
      <div className="w-full absolute top-[30%] bg-teal-800 left-0 h-[500px] -skew-y-12">

      </div>

    </motion.div>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```

This normally works on js but my compiler return:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

because it still considers the prop as an object, even if I try to access the array at the code above, how can i solve it?

Comment: @DreamBold Yes, but now when I build the app  using  sanity build, an error comes:[=   ] info  - Generating static pages (2/3)TypeError: projects.map is not a function

Comment: @DreamBold I don't know but when i console.log the technologies the JSON above comes out.

Comment: @DreamBold how can I send the json to you?  the comment box says it's too long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250698/discussion-between-arotiana-randrianasolo-and-dreambold).

Comment: @DreamBold https://pastebin.com/uTws3DHA sorry for the delay, I've just learned how to use pastebin

Comment: is the json data for `project` variable or `project.technologies`?

Comment: If you have anydesk, please send it to me so I can have a look at your project, or you can upload it to github and add me

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-cdn-5p3jos?file=/src/Projects.tsx

Comment: @DreamBold My internet connection is really slow now, I may not be able to commit the project now, but I'll see if it works fine tomorrow.  Thank you for your help, it's  very kind of you

Comment: @DreamBold In case the commit finishes early, may I get you GitHub Id?  And I wish to get in touch with you, can we discuss on social media?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do project?.technologies.map, but as i see at the JSON above , there is simply no "technologies" key.